# Capacitive touch: Board penetrations

Tags: capacitor, switches, touchscreen

If I place copper pads (for use as self-capacitance capacitive touch buttons) on the secondary side of a board and place adjacent to them surface-mount bottom-facing LEDs on the primary side of the board (with drilled penetrations such that they show through to the secondary side of the board adjacent to the buttons), will the nearby penetrations through the ground plane significantly affect the ability to register the self-capacitiance on the self-capacitance capacitive touch pad?